# Why is my wordpress localized var not avaliable in my front end js

Tags: wordpress, nonce

My goal is to localize a wordpress nonces to use for authorizations of a post request to the wp REST API from the adminpanel.

Problem is, that I can't get access to the nonces from javascript.

I have added wp_localize_script to the action that enqueue my javasript file:

```
function my_admin_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/script.js', false );

    $data = array(
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'script', 'wp_api_var', $data );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts' );
```

Then I would expect, that I could call this in my script.js file:

```
console.log (wp_api_var.nonces);
```

But I can't:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: wp_api_var is not defined
<anonymous> https://lisbjergbeboerforening.dk/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/js/script.js?ver=5.5.1:4
```

I understand from the error that my variable wp_api_var is not avaliable, but why?

BR Kresten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Localize script should be:

```
/*
* wp_localize_script( string $handle, string $object_name, array $l10n )
*
/*

wp_localize_script( 'admin-js', 'wp_api_var', $data );
```

Your script handle is `'admin-js'`

Comment: My script is named script not admin-js, so it was newer enqueued. But I could still use the js code.